# Is it possible to "sandbox" the JavaScript engine in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, sandbox, code-injection

I've got a really useful function in my program (written in Java) that allows the user to evaluate JavaScript functions and expressions. This is really useful for quick maths and times when you just need a for loop.
However, it has come to my attension that there is infinite possibility for a code injection attack: entering `exit()` will exit the entire program, for example. And as it runs the JS serverside, this is a HUGE problem.

This is my function (java code):

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
try {
    this.send(engine.eval(message /*user javascript*/).toString());
} catch (ScriptException e) {
    this.send("[ERROR] the expression was invalid and caused an exception. See the console for more details.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Is there a way to configure this so that the javascript engine cannot access functions like this? It's really handy to be able to define a simple function without having to go and open a python interpreter for example, so that's why it's important that I have this addmittedly insecure feature.

Comment: Check this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38464733/safely-running-javascript-code-in-java

Comment: @saravana Well I looked at it and it's half of the solution: I can block classes (I need a list of classes to block as well) but I don't know how to block functions like exit()

Comment: Check  about Graalvm, it may helps.